What does operator <=> do in PostgreSQL
I found such query in some of the working repository:
SELECT id, full_name_tsvector <=> plainto_tsquery('English', 'test') AS rank
FROM names_tsvectors 
WHERE "full_name_tsvector" @@ plainto_tsquery('English', 'test')
ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1000

The query gives result:
id   |rank     |
-----+---------+
 6574|13.159472|
25653|13.159472|
 5730|13.159472|
21924|13.159472|
 6578|13.159472|
 5813|13.159472|
22188| 16.44934|
21959| 16.44934|
20360| 16.44934|

So my question is - what does operator <=> do actually? I haven't found anything about that operator except that it does not exist in Postgres.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86773/what-does-the-postgres-operator-do

@MitchWheat thanks, but there is nothing about <=> operator. There is <-> instead/

I can't find any reference to <=> either. Could you check with \doS+ (in psql) if it shows up?

"I found such query in some of the working repository:" - can you provide a link please

@MitchWheat it's under NDA.

I run that query on dbeaver also and it works perfectly. But I can't find any reference to that operator..

PostgreSQL doesn't contain an operator with that name. You probably got it from an extension.
Figure out which extension that is using the query
SELECT oprname AS operator_name,
       oprnamespace::regnamespace AS operator_schema,
       e.extname AS extension_name
FROM pg_operator AS o
   JOIN pg_depend AS d
      ON d.classid = 'pg_operator'::regclass
         AND d.objid = o.oid
   JOIN pg_extension AS e
      ON d.refclassid = 'pg_extension'::regclass
         AND d.refobjid = e.oid
WHERE d.deptype = 'e'
  AND o.oprname = '<=>';

and look at the documentation of that software.

Thanks. I run the query and it shows rum

https://github.com/postgrespro/rum/blob/master/README.md
